# Load SharePoint users into choice column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a choice column who have items I setted manually like this:

[image]

Question is: Is it possible to charge Sharepoint users and load there instead manual options? Regards

Comment: Can't you use Person or Group column? Add users in a SharePoint group and assign that group to the Person column.

Comment: With person or group column I can achieve that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to achieve this.

1. Go to Site Settings and create a SharePoint Group under Users and Permissions -> People and groups.
2. Create a "Person or Group" column and assign the group created in step 1 as shown below

[image]

Comment: Can you share mr a link or explain how yo create group please?

Comment: @Ledwing please check point no 1 in my answer to create a SharePoint group. You need to add list of users in that group.